# Zebra LI2208 doesn't work properly in a intellistand

Tags: scanner, barcode-scanner, barcode

I put my scanner into the intellistand (STND-GS00UNC-04) and it didn't switch to presentation mode. I tried to enable hands-free mode a even factory reset but it didn't help.

Thanks

Comment: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/about-zebra/contact-zebra/contact-tech-support.html